# How to indent long frametitle (beamer)?

Tags: beamer, indentation

I have (sub)section numbers in the `\frametitle`, and I want an indentation if the frame title is too long to fit in one line (similar to default LaTeX behavior).
I fiddeled around with adding `\hangindent=3em` to the `\frametitle` argument but this does not help.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{1.1 A long frametitle that produces a linebreak line line line line line}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The desired outcome would be something like:

```
1.1 A long frametitle that produces a linebreak
    line line line line line
```

instead of

```
1.1 A long frametitle that produces a linebreak
line line line line line
```

Background: The whole `\frametitle` command with (sub)section number and actual (sub)section heading is generated by the following command:

```
\newcommand{\frametitledef}{\frametitle{
\ifnum\value{subsection}=0
  \thesection{} \insertsection{}
\else
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \thesection{}.\thesubsection{} \insertsubsection{}
  \else
    \thesection{}.\thesubsection{}.\thesubsubsection{} \insertsubsubsection{}
  \fi
\fi
}}
```

Comment: Do you want to indent the second line? How do you insert the section number. Maybe a simple `\llap{}` should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question corrcetly; perhaps you want something like this `\frametitle{\parbox[t]{.9\paperwidth}{\hangindent=1.6em\raggedright 1.1 A long frametitle that produces a linebreak line line line line line}}`?

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. @MarcoDaniel: In the actual presentation, the section numbers are generated via a command. If you are interested, I could post it. I tried with `\llap{}`, but could not solve the problem. @GonzaloMedina: Yes, you have understood correctly. Furthermore, it really does what I wanted. However, this still needs some manual tuning.

Comment: @JonasK: Please. It's easier to understand your question.

Comment: @JonasK: I think I now understand, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\frametitledef}{\frametitle{%
\ifnum\value{subsection}=0
  \parbox[t]{1em}{\thesection}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.9\paperwidth-1em\relax}{\insertsection}%
\else
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \parbox[t]{2em}{\thesection.\thesubsection}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.9\paperwidth-2em\relax}{\insertsubsection}%
  \else
    \parbox[t]{3em}{\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.9\paperwidth-3em\relax}{\insertsubsubsection}%
  \fi
\fi
}}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\frame{test}

\subsection{A long frametitle that produces a linebreak line line line line line}

\begin{frame}
\frametitledef

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's an image of the second frame showing the indentation for the second line of the title:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!