# Hangindent frametitle in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, frame-title

I'm trying to hang indent my long frametitles and can't find a solution how to do it. 
I tried to use

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hangindent=2cm Long Frametitle}

but that doesn't do anything. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. -
Does  [How to indent long frametitle (beamer)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47436/124842) help you?

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \hspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\dimexpr\the\@tempdima-1cm\relax]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\hskip-1cm\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Long Frametitle that spans two lines and goes on and on and on and on and on}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to recalculate \textheight.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Stupid question: why? The textheight is the same as for a multi-line frametitle without hanging indent. (not that the textheight makes sense in either of these cases, but this would be a job for beamer)

Comment: I noticed that there wasn't enough room for \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}, but there is never enough room if you include a title.  It's just the beamer way.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  Yes, textheight is currently not very useful in beamer. Unfortunately it seems not so easy to fix this, as things like framezoom make it more complicate.

Comment: Actually, I remember that the frame is composed  BEFORE the title, so there is no way to communicate the title height to the frame body.  \rule{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight-\baselineskip-.666em} is the right size for a single line title.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat less invasive solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox{\bigtitlebox}

\newcommand{\bigtitle}[1]% #1 = multiline frame title
{\bgroup
  \hsize=\dimexpr\paperwidth-.666em\relax
  \global\setbox\bigtitlebox=\vbox{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut#1\strut}%
\egroup
\frametitle{\usebox\bigtitlebox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\bigtitle{\hangindent=2cm
Long Frametitle that spans two lines and goes on and on and on and on and on}
%\frametitle{Normal title}
\rule{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight-\ht\bigtitlebox-\dp\bigtitlebox-.666em}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]